# Redirect all html pages except home page to php version

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

This works ok, but the problem is that http://www.example.com redirects to http://www.example.com/index.php. How do I inhibit the home page php redirect from happening while keeping all other pages redirected?

For example:

```
www.example.com/page1.html >> www.example.com/page1.php
www.example.com/page2.html >> www.example.com/page2.php
www.example.com >> www.example.com (i.e., nothing happpens)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` doesn't need `RewriteEngine On` line.

You can use this negative lookahead rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!index\.)(.+)\.html$ /$1.php
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it, but when I enter www.example.com in my browser, it still redirects to www.example.com/index.php. I would like to browser bar to remain as just: www.example.com

Comment: Try my updated rule and Make sure to clear your browser cache.